Hydrostatic paradox not resolved in this case?



For the first image given in my book, an explanation for the hydrostatic paradox is given and I agree. It says that the pressure of water due to each of the three sections acting on the water at the bottom is the same and hence the levels are the same.
We first think that the large volume hence greater weight of water in section A acts on a smaller area, whereas a similar large volume acts on a larger area in section B. And so we expect the pressure at the bottom of section A to be more than that for B. However, it's not the case because on the small area of A, only the weight of water shown in between the red lines (in second fig) acts, and for the rest of the water, it gets cancelled by the vertical component of the normal reaction given by the wall of that section. And so it's small $F$ on small $A$ and $F/A=P$ remains the same.
Now see the third image, the figure I have drawn. There, the frustum-of-cone shaped section is similar to section B of previous figure and has base area $A$. Next to it, the cylindrical section also has base area $A$. Now, if the levels are equal, clearly, the volume and hence weight of the water belonging to cylindrical section will be more than that of the frustum section. In this case, there's no wall to support the extra weight. So, on the same base area $A$, $F_{cylindrical} > F_{fructum}$, seems to be the case.
So, is the pressure at the two bases different? What would be the water levels? (If they're different, we expect frustum's water level to be higher than cylinder's. I've drawn the opposite, sorry.)

Also On hydrostatic pressure and weight and the link therein.

@Farcher Hmm. So you say reaction force given by the wall of frustum container compensates for the weight of the missing water. Is it possible to prove this theoretically?

Is it possible to prove this theoretically?  If there were no forces from the walls acting on the water the water would not stay in position. The best I can do is to say is that the walls exert a pressure on the water equal to the pressure exerted by contained water on the walls .
